# How to login into any website using Python Request

Tags: python, forms, curl, automation, python-requests

I'm planning to automation using python. For that, I need to log in into that website and check whether fields in main pages are available or not.

My input

request_url: www.gmail.com
payload: {'email':'email@example.com','password':'wrongpassword'}

```
def post_request_curl(data):
    headers = { 'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36' }
    try:   
           with requests.Session() as s:
              login_data=data['login_details']
              r = s.get(url=data['url'],header=headers)
              soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')
              login_data['form_build_id'] = soup.find('input', attrs={'name': 'form_build_id'})['value']
              r = s.post(url=data['url'], data=login_data, headers=headers)
              return r 

    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as t:
        logging.error('Error occurred ' + str(t))
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error('Error occurred ' + str(e))
```

Comment: Where does `headers` come from? Please read how to use the [Session](https://2.python-requests.org/en/v2.5.3/user/advanced/)

Comment: headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36'
}

Comment: @Pynchia Please go through it

Comment: How to get the post URL, csrf token from it

Comment: This probably isn't going to work at all for GMail. If you want general automation for sites that rely on JS, you should look into [Selenium](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/). If you just want to check GMail with a script, do it the right way, [via the API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api).